# INSUFFICIENT_DATA at Elastic Transcoder JobsErrored Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I configured an alarm to trigger when ever a Elastic Transcoder Job fails. For this I went to Cloud Watch, Created Alarm with these details:

```
Name: Job Error
Desc: Job Error
Whenever: JobErrored >=1 For 1 consecutive periods
```

But it is showing as `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`. Not sure what I am missing in this. Can anyone please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you run any transcoder jobs for the past few hours?  For most AWS services, if a configuration is idle for some period of time, it is normal for there to be "insufficient data" because an unused configuration will be sending no data at all to Cloudwatch. (e.g. I have observed that an SQS queue with no active producers or consumers will stop sending metrics after a few hours, and assume ETS would behave the same way.)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out